# Publisher not calling completion when test is async (case for M1 processor)

Tags: swift, async-await, xctest, combine, publisher

I have a class that can load data asynchronously from the file system. I am trying to test reading the data correctly and have been seeing how the publisher I create to call the loading task only finishes as long as the test is not marked as `async`.

I need the test to be `async` to be able to `await` saving the data to the file system before testing reading it. For the sake of demonstrating the failure, I have omitted that part. These are the tests I am running, one passing, the other one failing:

```
func testPassing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable() {
    let url = testSpecificStoreURL()
    let (publisher, _) = makeSUT(url: url)

    let expectedData = waitForPublication(on: publisher) ?? Data()
    XCTAssertEqual("Example data", String(data: expectedData, encoding: .utf8))
}

func testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable() async {
    let url = testSpecificStoreURL()
    let (publisher, _) = makeSUT(url: url)

    let expectedData = waitForPublication(on: publisher) ?? Data()
    XCTAssertEqual("Example data", String(data: expectedData, encoding: .utf8))
}
```

Notice how they are identical, except for the `func testFailing...` one being `async`.

The failing one fails with message:

```
.../TestingCombine/TestingCombineTests/CombineHelperTests.swift:93: error: -[TestingCombineTests.CombineHelperTests testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable] : Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 3 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Wait for publisher".
.../TestingCombine/TestingCombineTests/CombineHelperTests.swift:70: error: -[TestingCombineTests.CombineHelperTests testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable] : XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("Example data")") is not equal to ("Optional("")")
```

The helper methods `testSpecificationURL()`, `makeSUT(url:)` and `waitForPublication` can be found in this repository: https://github.com/lfcj/TestingCombine/blob/main/TestingCombineTests/CombineHelperTests.swift

It is a repo with only one important file to be able to reproduce.

The repo even has GitHub Actions and the `async` test also fails. The logs are very scarce for GitHub Actions, but the failure happens after timeout + a couple of milliseconds every time, example:

**When timeout is 3**

```
Test case 'CombineHelperTests.testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable()' failed on 'Clone 1 of iPhone 14 - TestingCombine (4572)' (3.114 seconds)
```

**When timeout is 5**

```
Test case 'CombineHelperTests.testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable()' failed on 'Clone 1 of iPhone 14 - TestingCombine (3784)' (5.194 seconds)
```

**When timeout is 10**

```
Test case 'CombineHelperTests.testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable()' failed on 'Clone 1 of iPhone 14 - TestingCombine (6248)' (10.121 seconds)
```

Any idea what is causing this to happen? A teacher of mine cannot reproduce on an Intel machine, I can reproduce each time on my M1.

**Update:** I was able to reproduce the issue on two different M1 devices every time. Not a single time for an Intel Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that we are "waiting" for the expectation, not `await`ing for it. Using:

```
@MainActor func waitForExpectations(timeout: TimeInterval, handler: XCWaitCompletionHandler? = nil)
```

takes care of waiting until the `Task` is done. More information can be found [in Apple Forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/tasks-closure-not-called-in-async-xctest-function/59093/4).

So the solution is doing:

```
func testFailing_localSavedLocallyIsUsedWhenAvailable() async {
        let url = testSpecificStoreURL()
        let (publisher, _) = makeSUT(url: url)

        let exp = expectation(description: "Wait for publisher")
        var expectedData = Data()
        publisher.sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                exp.fulfill()
            },
            receiveValue: { receivedData in
                expectedData = receivedData
            }
        ).store(in: &cancellables)
        
        await waitForExpectations(timeout: 3)
        XCTAssertEqual("Example data", String(data: expectedData, encoding: .utf8))
}
```